# How can I describe the painted lower section of a wall?

Tags: sentence-construction

For example there is a wall. The lower section of this wall is orange and the height of orange part is 1 meter. Can I say sentences below when I talking about this wall or should I describe it in a few sentences as above?

> There is a wall with the 1 meter high orange lower section.

> There is a wall that is orange from bottom to the height of 1 meter.

> The wall’s lower section from bottom to the height of 1 meter is orange

Comment: Is it "wainscoting"  ... "The wainscoting is painted orange."

Comment: Actually I just want to learn if my senteces are good. Are all sentece clear enough for a native speakers?

Comment: @JamesK a [wainscot](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wainscot) is wood panelling etc in it the lower part of a wall.

Comment: It's good to ask for a good way to express something, but just asking "is it correct" is rather tedious proofreading (and considered off topic)

Comment: Yes "dado" is better.

Comment: If your question is just about "are these sentences correct" and not about any specific aspect of English, then this question is off-topic as we don't do proofreading on this site. If you are unsure about some specific function or aspect of English in those sentences, please edit your question to make it clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I offer **dado**. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dado) has

> **dado**
>
> the lower part of the wall inside a room, when this is painted a different colour or covered in different paper from the upper part
>
> *We've painted the dado a dark mulberry colour and the rest of the wall off-white.*

Comment: When someone who is not a native speaker lile me says sentences above would you understand and would they be correct?

Comment: @languagelearner I've never heard the word "dado". My guess is almost nobody would understand this.

Comment: I know the term because I once worked in the building industry. There is no reason to dumb down a language, and every reason to enrich one's vocabulary.

Comment: @gotube Actually I asked about my senteces. Are all of them correct and understandable?

Comment: @languagelearner your sentences are correct, apart from two things. The first sentence should (arguably) use the *indirect* article – "***a*** 1 metre high section." And your spelling of metre as meter. A [meter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meter) is a device, but a [metre](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metre) is the SI unit of length, although some dialects confuse the two.

Comment: Thank you @WeatherVane.

Comment: @gotube - fairly familiar to anyone in the UK who has been interested in decor. Some people call a wooden rail that separates the two colours a 'dado' or 'dado rail' as well. My childhood home's kitchen/dining room had a vinyl wallpaper dado that imitated ceramic tiles.

Comment: @languagelearner more generally, consider revising the use of **articles** in the other sentences too. It's not really clear-cut here, though, but for example I might write "There is a wall that is orange from ***the*** bottom to ***a*** height of 1 meter."